# How to view access token generated by Azure AD in ASP.NET Core API?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, azure-active-directory

How to **view** the access token generated by Azure AD in ASP.NET Core 5.0 Web Api?

For more context:

I have an Angular client which is getting an access token after logging in with MSAL V2. The client can call the API with the acquired access token. How can I intercept the token? I want to get the username or/and e-mail address from it.

```
services.AddAuthentication(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
    .AddMicrosoftIdentityWebApi(Configuration.GetSection("AzureAD"));
```

Comment: Do you want to see the raw access token or find information about the user embedded in the token?

Comment: It would be perfect to get the user only. I want to save the user info on first login.

Answer (score 1):

Use the below code to  find the token from the user claim:

```
var identity = HttpContext.User.Identity as ClaimsIdentity;
if (identity != null)
{
  IEnumerable<Claim> claims = identity.Claims; 
  // or
  identity.FindFirst("ClaimName").Value;

}
```

For more information you can follow the below article for more understanding:
https://visualstudiomagazine.com/articles/2019/11/01/authorization-claims.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Getting the user information is quite straight forward.

In every controller, you get access to [`HttpContext`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.http.httpcontext?view=aspnetcore-5.0) object and that has a [`User`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.http.httpcontext.user?view=aspnetcore-5.0#Microsoft_AspNetCore_Http_HttpContext_User) property. You can check user's claims to find their name and other information about the user.

Comment: Thank you, exactly what I needed!